# Jquery: Help. Wrapping images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Need some help. I have a div of images.

```
<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
  <ul class="thumbs">
    <p>
      <img src="assets/images/example-1.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" />      
      <img src="assets/images/example-2.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" />
      <img src="assets/images/example-3.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" />
      <img src="assets/images/example-4.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" />
      <img src="assets/images/example-5.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" />
      <img src="assets/images/example-6.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" />
      <img src="assets/images/example-7.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" />
    </p>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to get all the images, wrap them in an anchor `<a href="">` with the `href` being the src of the image, and then wrap each one within a `<li>`

This is what I have so far:

```
    var b = $('#thumbs > .thumbs'); // Get a reference to the banner div
    var i = b.find('img'); // Pull all the images
    var src = i.attr('src');
    b.empty().append(i); // Empty the banner div, and replace the images
    b.find('img').wrap('<li><a href="' + src + '" /></li>'); // Wrap the images
```

This sort of works, but I have multiple divs on a page, each have different images, and the jquery is now pulling all the images from each div and adding them all together. So basically I need this JQuery for each individual `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function like this...

```
$.fn.ParseImages = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        var b = $(this).find('#thumbs > .thumbs'); // Get a reference to the banner div
        var i = b.find('img'); // Pull all the images
        var src = i.attr('src');
        b.empty().append(i); // Empty the banner div, and replace the images
        b.find('img').wrap('<li><a href="' + src + '" /></li>'); // Wrap the images
    });
};
```

Then call the code like this...

```
$(function() {
    $("div.navigation").ParseImages();
});
```

That would run the function on every div with the class "navigation".

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem to work. I am putting the top part of the code before my function call, then the second part within the function call, as I have other Jquery I am using.

Comment: I've just made a slight change to the top code, so try updating it. Also, when you add the 2nd bit of code, make sure you just add the middle line.  Not sure if you know, but the outer part - $(function() etc. - is just to make it run when the document has loaded.

Comment: Hi. Still not working I'm afraid. I am doing as you said. Putting the top code outside the document ready and the bottom code within a document ready function

Comment: Any chance you could put an example on jsfiddle so it can be fixed for you?  The above code _does_ work, so there must be another reason that you're having problems.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest making a jQuery function, much as @[Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023618/archer) did, in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758811/82548), such as:

```
$.fn.imgTidy = function() {
    // finds the images within the child '.thumbs' div of $(this).
    var images = $(this).find('.thumbs img');
    var iLength = images.length;

    // iterates through each of the resulting image nodes, wrapping each in an 'li' element
    $(images).each(
        function(){
            $(this).wrap('<li></li>');
        });

    /* if the parent node of the first 'li' element (assuming they all share a common
       parent, so nested lists are going to be problematic with this approach) is
       _not_ a 'ul' this unwraps all the list elements returned by the
      '$('.thumbs li')' selector */

    if( $('.thumbs li:first').parent().not('ul') ){
        $('.thumbs li').unwrap();
    }

    // returns the node(s) for chaining.
    return $(this);
};
```

And calling it as such:

```
$('#thumbs').imgTidy();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TDkKN/).